# How to expand a container in flutter with overflowing container in which it is contained ? Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation, expandable, ontap

I want to expand my container on click. in Flutter
[image: this is what I have now]

The green containers are contained within a blueishgrey container. The 5 green containers are in a listview builder. When I tap any of the containers, it needs to expand to its right side.

[image: this is the result I want]

like in the above image

Comment: can you include your current snippet

Comment: You might want to use Overlays:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fhkaDua0rhE

https://blog.logrocket.com/complete-guide-implementing-overlays-flutter/